# Hosting a login-gated content on a jekyll blog

Tags: vue.js, jekyll

I'm hosting a static Jekyll website with written markdown content on Netlify (e.g. like cooking recipes or something). I'd like to integrate a login flow so that some of the html pages are visible to members only, but my understanding is that this is not possible on static jekyll websites. Is that the case or is there a simple way to add members-only content on Jekyll?

I can do this trivially by writing some vue.js code, but I also want to preserve the ability to render markdown->html. Is there a way that I can get login-gated content on Jekyll natively, or somehow get some other web framework to render Jekyll-compiled content correctly?

Comment: What did you tried so far? How can you expect to protect the content if the files are static + you're planning to do that with JS on client side? The user could disable the JS and access your static page.

Comment: It depends on your hosting service. Jekyll as it is doesn't provide you with what you need.